# When I swap out return for print, I don' t get all the same values back

Tags: python, function

when I swap return for print, I do not get all the same values back in my defined function.

Here is my code with print()

```
def seo():
    sou = soup.findAll(class_ = 'rtf l-row')
    for x in sou:
        l = x.findAll('p')
        s = x.findAll('h4')
        for i in l:
            lolz = i.text
            print(lolz)
        for j in s:
            h = j.text
            print(h)
```

Here is the exact same code with return:

```
def seo():
    sou = soup.findAll(class_ = 'rtf l-row')
    for x in sou:
        l = x.findAll('p')
        s = x.findAll('h4')
        for i in l:
            lolz = i.text
            return lolz
        for j in s:
            h = j.text
            return h
```

when I use return, I only get back the first line of code. Thanks!

Comment: Reformat your code.

Comment: Everything after a return statement is not executed any more. If you want to get both data from `l` and `s`, you have to save it and return it both at the end, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7129293/2648551

Comment: The first version of the function doesn't return *anything*, it only prints things — so your question desn't quite make sense…

Answer (score 0):

**There should be only one return statement in a function, and it should be the last statement in it.**

You have two return statements inside your `seo` function. The function reaches the first return statement, and the rest of the code in the function never runs.

You should either break it into two different functions, or return a list or a dictionary so you can have several values returned in a single variable :)